# Почему json_decode на данном объекте может не работать?

Tags: php, json

Ниже представлен HTTP-запрос. Мне нужно извлечь из него данные - массив с ключами cells и distance.

```
 curl http://localhost:80/problem2.php -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json --data-binary "{'cells': [4,8,11,18,19], 'distance': 2}"
```

Но ничего не выходит, так как данные считываются не верно. Ниже - считывание данных.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Известно, что `file_get_contents('php://input')` точно получает данный массив. Почему `json_decode()` может не рабоать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON строго регламентирует использование двойных кавычек:

> ```
> --data-binary '{"cells": [4,8,11,18,19], "distance": 2}'
> ```

```
var_dump(json_decode('{"cells": [4,8,11,18,19], "distance": 2}'));
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/hG7cZ)

Comment: сделано. Но всё равно не работает

Comment: Добавил пруф, что json_decode работает

Comment: При таком запросе всё работает корректно: `curl http://htaccess.loc/problem.php -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json --data-binary '{"cells": [4,8,11,18,19], "distance": 2}'`

Answer (score 1):

> Но ничего не выходит, так как данные считываются не верно. Ниже - считывание данных.
>
> `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

При условии, что у вас есть файл `problem2.php` и сервер слушает на `localhost:80`, а не на `8080` или другом порте.

`json_decode` возвращает объект типа *stdClass*, обращатся к нему надо

```
print_r($data->cells);
```

Выхлоп:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 18
    [4] => 19
)
```